# Pass Visualforce input fields to Controller - get Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.CallCycle__c'

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I am struggling to get my simple VF page to work as I keep getting an *'Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.CallCycle__c'* error. Below is my VF form, and below that my Controller. I first tried just having the 2 variables CCStart and CCEnd and to use those on the form, but that also didn't work - I get the error *'Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!CCStart}'.  <apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable*'. I then changed it to using the custom object instead, but that throws the other error. Please tell me where I'm going wrong - using the variables would be better, as I only need those for my query.

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account" extensions="AccountContactListRequestController" sidebar="true" showHeader="true">
<apex:form >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Account Contacts Print" subtitle="Request a print of Contacts for Accounts/Call Cycle range" />

        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:PageMessages />

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton id="Print" value="Print Contacts" action="{!PrintContacts}" />
                <apex:commandButton id="Clear" value="Clear" action="{!Clear}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Call Schedule Cycle Details" columns="1">

                <apex:inputField id="account" label="Account" value="{!Acct.Name}" required="true" />
                <apex:inputField id="cycleStart" label="Call Cycle Start" value="{!CallCycle__c.CycleStart__c}" />
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:inputField id="cycleEnd" label="Call Cycle End" value="{!CallCycle__c.CycleEnd__c}" />

            </apex:pageBlockSection>


        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
```

```
global with sharing class AccountContactListRequestController {

public string AccountId { get; set; }
public string CCStart { get; set; }
public string CCEnd { get; set; }
public list<Id> AccountIds { get; set; }
public list<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
public CallCycle__c CallCycle { get; set; }
public Account Acct {get; set; }

ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl;

public string dtNow {
    get { 
            string dNow = String.valueOf(System.Now());
            return dNow;
        }  
}   

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public AccountContactListRequestController(ApexPages.StandardController std) {

    stdCtrl=std;        
    AccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    CallCycle = new CallCycle__c();
    Acct = (Account)std.getRecord();

    //set the account
    if(AccountId != null){
        Accounts = [Select Id, Name, Owner.Name, AccountNumber
                    From Account 
                    Where Id = : AccountId];
    }
    else{
        Accounts = [Select Id, Name, Owner.Name, AccountNumber
                    From Account 
                    Where OtherPartyCode__c >=: CCStart and OtherPartyCode__c <=: CCEnd];            
    }
    //get the contacts
    List<Contact> contacts = [Select Id, Name, MobilePhone, Phone, Extension__c, Email, Title, Department, Generic_Department__c,
                                       AccredoCRMGroup__c, LastCallCycleVisitOn__c, Last_Memo_Date__c, PreferredContactMethod__c,
                                       Preferred_Day__c, Preferred_Time__c, Preferred_Time_Other__c, Role__c
                                       From Contact
                                       Where AccountId = : accountId and Inactive__c = false
                                       Order By Generic_Department__c desc, Name asc];



    system.debug(contacts.size());
    system.debug(Accounts);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public PageReference PrintContacts() {

    return ApexPages.CurrentPage();

}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public PageReference Clear() {

    return ApexPages.CurrentPage();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The __C seems to be culprit .You will need to use exact variable names as you have declared as a getter and setter variable.Using __c will mean SFDC compile time engine will look your variable as standard field on the Account record .Below is the corrected piece of code

```
<apex:inputField id="cycleStart" label="Call Cycle Start" value="{!CallCycle.CycleStart__c}" />
  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
 <apex:inputField id="cycleEnd" label="Call Cycle End" value="{!CallCycle.CycleEnd__c}" />
```